# SQL Server Insert Into Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I'm trying to `INSERT` a value in a column, the result of a `SELECT` this sentence works fine:

```
insert into tempdepa (Trabajadores) 
   (select count (DepartmentName) 
    from DimEmployee 
    where DepartmentName = @d)
```

But I want to insert that `SELECT` into a specific column:

```
insert into tempdepa (Trabajadores) 
   (select count (DepartmentName) 
    from DimEmployee 
    where DepartmentName = @d)
```

where id = @cont

This last `where id = @cont` is from the first table (tempdepa)... I tried

```
insert into tempdepa (Trabajadores where id = @cont) 
    (select count (DepartmentName) 
     from DimEmployee 
     where DepartmentName = @d)
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: Not clear at all,but I think you need a JOIN.

Comment: You probably need to use an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT` if you want to change the value of an **existing** row! The `INSERT` cannot be "parametrized" with a `WHERE` clause - it just **inserts** a new row.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to insert new row, you need to do:

```
insert into tempdepa (Trabajadores, id)
select count(DepartmentName), @cont
from DimEmployee where DepartmentName = @d
```

if you want to update existing one:

```
update tempdepa
set Trabajadores=(select count (DepartmentName) from DimEmployee where DepartmentName = @d)
where id = @cont
```

Comment: Lashane's got it. An INSERT is only used when you are creating **a whole new row**. You need to use an UPDATE if you are changing a field on an existing row.

Comment: WOW THANK YOU ALL! YOU WERE RIGHT @LASHANE I DIDNT REALIZED THAT I WAS INSERTIN NEW ROWS... BUT I NEEDED TO UPDATE :D THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!